# Java : final constructor

Tags: java

Read this question i thought reason is not enough and also not clear for me. Can you please elaborate

**Q) Can we declare a constructor final?**

No, because constructor is never inherited.

Comment: You could also say the constructor is automatically "inherited" or called: you have a super() first in each constructor (not necessairy to write it unless you want to specify parameters).

Comment: Do you understand that a constructor is not a member of a class and it cannot be inherited? Do you understand that `final` means "cannot be overridden"? Do you understand that overriding is only relevant to methods that are inherited?